# Loop over groups Pandas Dataframe and get sum/count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, sum

I am using Pandas to structure and process Data.
This is my DataFrame:

[image: DataFrame]

And this is the code which enabled me to get this DataFrame:

```
(data[['time_bucket', 'beginning_time', 'bitrate', 2, 3]].groupby(['time_bucket', 'beginning_time', 2, 3])).aggregate(np.mean)
```

Now I want to have the sum (Ideally, the sum and the count) of my 'bitrates' grouped in the same time_bucket. For example, for the first time_bucket((2016-07-08 02:00:00, 2016-07-08 02:05:00), it must be 93750000 as sum and 25 as count, for all the case 'bitrate'.

I did this :

```
data[['time_bucket', 'bitrate']].groupby(['time_bucket']).agg(['sum', 'count'])
```

And this is the result :

[image]

But I really want to have all my data in one DataFrame.

Can I do a simple loop over 'time_bucket' and apply a function which calculate the sum of all bitrates ?
Any ideas ? Thx !

Comment: Please provide a small code snippet that provides the dataframes needed for your question (or a small approximation of them). These images can't be loaded into Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), but need same levels of `indexes` of both `DataFrames`, so use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). Last get original `Multiindex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,1,1],
                     'B':[4,4,4,5,5,5],
                     'C':[3,3,3,1,1,1],
                     'D':[1,3,1,3,1,3],
                     'E':[5,3,6,5,7,1]})

print (data)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  4  3  1  5
1  1  4  3  3  3
2  1  4  3  1  6
3  1  5  1  3  5
4  1  5  1  1  7
5  1  5  1  3  1
```

```
df1 = data[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E']].groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']).aggregate(np.mean)
print (df1)
           E
A B C D     
1 4 3 1  5.5
      3  3.0
  5 1 1  7.0
      3  3.0

df2 = data[['A', 'C']].groupby(['A'])['C'].agg(['sum', 'count'])
print (df2)
   sum  count
A            
1   12      6

print (pd.merge(df1.reset_index(['B','C','D']), df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
         .set_index(['B','C','D'], append=True))

           E  sum  count
A B C D                 
1 4 3 1  5.5   12      6
      3  3.0   12      6
  5 1 1  7.0   12      6
      3  3.0   12      6
```

I try another solution to get output from `df1`, but this is aggregated so it is impossible get right data. If sum level `C`, you get `8` instead `12`.

Comment: Can u help me to do this ? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691671/resampling-timeseries-with-a-given-timedelta

Comment: Yes, please see my solution.